# Cannot call method 'send' of undefined(response is undefined) in express js

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

I have tried to pass a variable from my index.html to the database(maildata.js) through app.js(server) and get the corresponding data
I am able to get the data from the database but couldnt send that back to the server(app.js)

app.js

```
var express = require('express');
var maildata= require('./maildata');
var app = express();
app.configure(function(){
app.use(express.bodyParser());
});

app.get('/', function(request, response){
response.sendfile(__dirname + '/mailbox.html');
});
app.post('/mailboxpost',function(request, response) {
    var input=request.query.search;     
var result=maildata.getMailData(input); 
response.send(result);
response.end();
});

app.listen(8888);
console.log('Server is running on port 8888');
```

maildata.js

```
    exports.getMailData=function(data,response) {

    var stop_name= data;    
    connection.query("select stop_name,stop_comment from stoplist where stop_name=        '"+stop_name+"' limit 1",function(err, rows) {    

    if (err) {
        console.log('error in fetching  ' + err);   
    }
    else{    
        var jsonString1= JSON.stringify(rows);
    connection.query("select mailbox_sequence_no from stoplist where stop_name= '"+stop_name+"'",function(err, rows) {  

    if (err) {
        console.log('error in fetching  ' + err);   
    }
    else{    
        var jsonString2 = JSON.stringify(rows);
         connection.query("select party_head from stoplist where stop_name= '"+stop_name+"'", function(err, rows) { 
     if (err) {
        console.log('error in fetching  ' + err);   
     }
     else{  
        var jsonString3 = JSON.stringify(rows);
        var result=jsonString1+'/'+jsonString2+'/'+jsonString3;  
        response.send(result);    
      }    
    });
   }    
  });    
 }    
});    
}
```

Thanks in Advance

Comment: You have to handle callback properly in "app.post"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have used asynchronous callback method in my app.js.

I got the result

```
var result=maildata.getMailData(input,response,function(data){
response.send(data);
response.end();
});
```

Thanks all

Answer (score 1):

How about sending response along when you call the function?

`var result=maildata.getMailData(input); // something missing here`

Answer (score 0):

Your `getMailData` function expects two arguments:

```
exports.getMailData=function(data,response) { ... }
```

but you give it only one:

```
var result=maildata.getMailData(input);
```

Which makes the value of the `response` argument `undefined`.

Here is what you should do:

```
app.post('/mailboxpost',function(request, response) {
  var input=request.query.search;     
  maildata.getMailData(input, response); 
});
```

and let `maildata.getMailData` handle the response sending, as you did in `response.send(result);`

Comment: Thanks.I have tried this already.But I got the following error.Please advice. "Error: Can't set headers after they are sent."

Comment: You call twice `res.send()`, which makes Express send the headers twice. You only need to call this function once, preferably in the callback of `maildata.getMailData`.